# General form of a matrix within the support of another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a Hermitian matrix which (after diagonalizing) is expressed as $$A = \sum_i a_i v_i v_i^*,$$ where $a_i$ are the eigenvalues, $v_i$ are the eigenvectors expressed as a column vector and $v_i^*$ is the transpose conjugate of $v_i$ i.e. a row vector.

I am given some other matrix $B$ (it is okay to assume that this is also Hermitian if needed) whose support is contained by the support of $A$. Here the support is defined as

$$\text{supp}(A) = \{u\in V| \langle u, v\rangle = 0, v\in \text{ker}(A)\}$$

What is the most general way to express $B$ if $\text{supp}(B)\subseteq \text{supp}(A)$?

Comment: sticking with Hermitian matrices then support of $X$ is the same as $\text{image}\big(X\big)$ is it not?

Comment: @user8675309 Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose that $a_1,\dots,a_r$ are the non-zero eigenvalues of $A$. The support of $A$ is spanned by $v_1,\dots,v_r$.

A Hermitian matrix $B$ will have its support contained in that of $A$ if and only if there exists a Hermitian $r \times r$ matrix $M$ for which $B = \sum_{i,j = 1}^r m_{ij} v_iv_j^*$. Equivalently, if $V$ is the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_r$, then $M$ is such that $B = VMV^*$.

---

For the case that $B$ is not Hermitian, $B$ will have a support contained in that of $A$ if and only if the kernel of $B$ contains that of $A$, which occurs if and only if $B$ can be expressed in the form $B = MV^*$ for some $n \times r$ matrix $M$ (where $n$ is the size of $A$).

---

Further discussion for the Hermitian case: here's an explanation via block-matrix multiplication.

Let $v_1,\dots,v_{r},v_{r+1},\dots,v_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb C^n$. As before, take $V$ to be the matrix with columns $v_1,\dots,v_r$, and take $W$ to be the matrix with columns $v_{r+1},\dots,v_{n}$. Note that $[V \ \ W]$ is a unitary matrix.

Because the kernel of $B$ contains the span of $v_{r+1},\dots,v_n$, we have $BW = 0$ and $W^*B = (BW)^* = 0$. With that, we note that
$$
[V \ \ W]^* B [V \ \ W] = \pmatrix{V^*BV & V^*BW\\ W^*BV & W^*BW} = \pmatrix{V^*BV & 0\\0 & 0}.
$$
Now, let $M = V^*BV$. Note that $M$ is Hermitian. We have
$$
B = (V\ \ W)\pmatrix{M & 0\\ 0 & 0} (V\ \ W)^* = VMV^*,
$$
which is what we wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand your statement that the kernel of $B$ contains that of $A$ but would you mind elaborating on why that leads to the form for $B$? I am more interested in the Hermitian case and a rough intuition/sketch of the proof would help me understand it a lot better. Thank you.

Comment: @user I'm just seeing your response now. I'll edit my answer to try to address this